# How to group column header based on multiple condition in SSRS matrix report?

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I am using SSRS Reporting service for report generation as a part of my project. I am using matrix report format. I have to Group the column headers, the problem I'm facing now is that I need to group column based on two conditions (not two separate groups). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a tablix group has been created, you can add more grouping expressions as required:

[image]

In this example I've opened and existing group and added a new grouping expression; here it's grouping by two Dataset fields.